# Hidden Inherritance c#

Tags: c#, inheritance, reflection, hidden, sealed

In c#, is it possible to prevent the programmer to inherit a parent class, but allow child classes to be inherited from (perhaps just during the writing of the code, not during runtime)?

For example:

```
//Class which should only allow 'RangedAbility' and 'MeleeAbility' to inherit. 
//No other classes are to be allowed to inherit from Ability
public abstract class Ability{ 
    public virtual void foo(){}
}

public class RangedAbility : Ability{
     //an empty class
}
public class MeleeAbility : Ability{
     //an empty class
}

public class myAbility : MeleeAbility{
     public override void foo(){ /*some code*/}
} 
//attempting to inherit from `Ability` instead of `MeleeAbility` or instead of 'RangedAbility' 
//should result in programmer facing an error in IDE such as Visual Studio.
```

Using "sealed" on `Ability` will not work (it is abstract, as well as `RangedAbility`, `MeleeAbility` need to inherit from it).
[Reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29808176/3593478) approach to "simmulate" inheritance by those two child classes would be very tedious and had to be done in both `MeleeAbility` and `RangedAbility`.
Abandoning the use of `Ability` completely, and forcing `RangedAbility` and `MeleeAbility` to implement an interface doesn't seem like a good option either, because they share methods that would be better-off written once through a "hidden" parent class.

The reason for doing such code is that I need to determine at runtime what kind of behavior to expect from 'myAbility' type. It is done through `IsSubclassOf(typeof(MeleeAbility))` or `IsSubclassOf(typeof(RangedAbility))`, which allows to determine expected behavior *without* needing an actual instance of `myAbility`.

Comment: Seems really weird to me, in particular relying on the actual type seems like a hack which should probably be achieved by overriding the method in your derived class instead of making a distinction on the type within the base-class. Basically a base-class shouldn´t depend on or know anything of its derived ones.

Comment: You are trying to bend OO principles with this approach. Not sure this is a good idea.

Comment: The reason for explicit testing is to store `System.Type` in a list, allowing to automatically instantiate objects at runtime. Storing a list of "string"will be a lengthy solution, because I would have to still perform conversion into type before creating an instance. Working in Unity3D, it's needed for user to type in a Type as a string, which gets serialized internally, by unity. Hence the classes to be instantiated can be determined by the end user during runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public abstract class Ability
{
  internal Ability()
  {
  }

  public virtual void foo(){}
}
```

Because the only constructor for `Ability` is `internal` only a derived class from within the same assembly can be constructed (constructors that don't explicitly build on a base constructor are implicitly `: base()`). Any attempt for a class in another assembly to derive directly from `Ability` will not have a valid constructor.

(On a related note, you might find an internal abstract property that your own classes override to return different values as neater method of determining which you have than doing explicit `IsSubClassOf` or even `is` tests. Or better again, providing whatever functionality turns on such a test through an internal abstract method).

Comment: Seems also hacky to me, deriving from a class but not being able to instantiate it because the base-class-constructor is not accessable. However this is by far the least dirty solution to achieve OPs needs.

Comment: Thank you Jon, this is the solution I needed. Never worked with `internal` before. The reason for explicit testing is to store `System.Type` in a list, allowing to automatically instantiate objects at runtime. Storing a list of "string"will be a lengthy solution, because I would have to still perform conversion into type before creating an instance. Working in Unity3D, it's needed for user to type in a Type as a string, which gets serialized internally, by unity. Hence the classes to be instantiated can be determined by the end user during runtime. 

Thanks for your help!

Comment: @HimBromBeere it's a common enough pattern.